# How to solve bad request when it's goes to server codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

I have a problem when try to build server
The problem are when i try to run locally it's work
but when i push to the server i got bad request on my url web

here some example

[image]

and here is in my local

[image]

here is my config.php

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Base Site URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
    | WITH a trailing slash:
    |
    |   http://example.com/
    |
    | WARNING: You MUST set this value!
    |
    | If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
    | your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
    | to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
    | The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
    | development and MUST NOT be used in production!
    |
    | If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
    | a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
    |
    */
    $config['base_url'] = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Index File
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
    | something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
    | variable so that it is blank.
    |
    */
    $config['index_page'] = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | URI PROTOCOL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
    | URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
    | If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
    |
    | 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    | 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
    | 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
    |
    | WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
    */
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | URL suffix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
    | For more information please see the user guide:
    |
    | https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
    */
    $config['url_suffix'] = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Language
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
    | there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
    | than english.
    |
    */
    $config['language'] = 'english';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Character Set
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
    | that require a character set to be provided.
    |
    | See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars for a list of supported charsets.
    |
    */
    $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable/Disable System Hooks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you would like to use the 'hooks' feature you must enable it by
    | setting this variable to TRUE (boolean).  See the user guide for details.
    |
    */
    $config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Extension Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This item allows you to set the filename/classname prefix when extending
    | native libraries.  For more information please see the user guide:
    |
    | https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
    | https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
    |
    */
    $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Composer auto-loading
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enabling this setting will tell CodeIgniter to look for a Composer
    | package auto-loader script in application/vendor/autoload.php.
    |
    |   $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
    |
    | Or if you have your vendor/ directory located somewhere else, you
    | can opt to set a specific path as well:
    |
    |   $config['composer_autoload'] = '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
    |
    | For more information about Composer, please visit http://getcomposer.org/
    |
    | Note: This will NOT disable or override the CodeIgniter-specific
    |   autoloading (application/config/autoload.php)
    */
    $config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Allowed URL Characters
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This lets you specify which characters are permitted within your URLs.
    | When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed characters they will
    | get a warning message.
    |
    | As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
    | as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
    |
    | Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
    |
    | The configured value is actually a regular expression character group
    | and it will be executed as: ! preg_match('/^[<permitted_uri_chars>]+$/i
    |
    | DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
    |
    */
    $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable Query Strings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
    | example.com/who/what/where/
    |
    | You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
    | example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
    |
    | Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
    |
    | The other items let you set the query string 'words' that will
    | invoke your controllers and its functions:
    | example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
    |
    | Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
    | this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
    | use segment based URLs.
    |
    */
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
    $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
    $config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
    $config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Allow $_GET array
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default CodeIgniter enables access to the $_GET array.  If for some
    | reason you would like to disable it, set 'allow_get_array' to FALSE.
    |
    | WARNING: This feature is DEPRECATED and currently available only
    |          for backwards compatibility purposes!
    |
    */
    $config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Error Logging Threshold
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
    | threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
    |
    |   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
    |   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
    |   2 = Debug Messages
    |   3 = Informational Messages
    |   4 = All Messages
    |
    | You can also pass an array with threshold levels to show individual error types
    |
    |   array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages
    |
    | For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
    | your log files will fill up very fast.
    |
    */
    $config['log_threshold'] = 0;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Error Logging Directory Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
    | application/logs/ directory. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
    |
    */
    $config['log_path'] = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log File Extension
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The default filename extension for log files. The default 'php' allows for
    | protecting the log files via basic scripting, when they are to be stored
    | under a publicly accessible directory.
    |
    | Note: Leaving it blank will default to 'php'.
    |
    */
    $config['log_file_extension'] = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log File Permissions
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The file system permissions to be applied on newly created log files.
    |
    | IMPORTANT: This MUST be an integer (no quotes) and you MUST use octal
    |            integer notation (i.e. 0700, 0644, etc.)
    */
    $config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Date Format for Logs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Each item that is logged has an associated date. You can use PHP date
    | codes to set your own date formatting
    |
    */
    $config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Error Views Directory Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
    | application/views/errors/ directory.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
    |
    */
    $config['error_views_path'] = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Directory Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
    | application/cache/ directory.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
    |
    */
    $config['cache_path'] = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Include Query String
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Whether to take the URL query string into consideration when generating
    | output cache files. Valid options are:
    |
    |   FALSE      = Disabled
    |   TRUE       = Enabled, take all query parameters into account.
    |                Please be aware that this may result in numerous cache
    |                files generated for the same page over and over again.
    |   array('q') = Enabled, but only take into account the specified list
    |                of query parameters.
    |
    */
    $config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you use the Encryption class, you must set an encryption key.
    | See the user guide for more info.
    |
    | https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html
    |
    */
    $config['encryption_key'] = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Variables
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | 'sess_driver'
    |
    |   The storage driver to use: files, database, redis, memcached
    |
    | 'sess_cookie_name'
    |
    |   The session cookie name, must contain only [0-9a-z_-] characters
    |
    | 'sess_expiration'
    |
    |   The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
    |   Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.
    |
    | 'sess_save_path'
    |
    |   The location to save sessions to, driver dependent.
    |
    |   For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
    |   WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
    |
    |   For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
    |   Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
    |
    |   IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!
    |
    | 'sess_match_ip'
    |
    |   Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data.
    |
    |   WARNING: If you're using the database driver, don't forget to update
    |            your session table's PRIMARY KEY when changing this setting.
    |
    | 'sess_time_to_update'
    |
    |   How many seconds between CI regenerating the session ID.
    |
    | 'sess_regenerate_destroy'
    |
    |   Whether to destroy session data associated with the old session ID
    |   when auto-regenerating the session ID. When set to FALSE, the data
    |   will be later deleted by the garbage collector.
    |
    | Other session cookie settings are shared with the rest of the application,
    | except for 'cookie_prefix' and 'cookie_httponly', which are ignored here.
    |
    */
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH. 'cache/session';
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cookie Related Variables
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | 'cookie_prefix'   = Set a cookie name prefix if you need to avoid collisions
    | 'cookie_domain'   = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
    | 'cookie_path'     = Typically will be a forward slash
    | 'cookie_secure'   = Cookie will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
    | 'cookie_httponly' = Cookie will only be accessible via HTTP(S) (no javascript)
    |
    | Note: These settings (with the exception of 'cookie_prefix' and
    |       'cookie_httponly') will also affect sessions.
    |
    */
    $config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
    $config['cookie_domain']    = '';
    $config['cookie_path']      = '/';
    $config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
    $config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Standardize newlines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Determines whether to standardize newline characters in input data,
    | meaning to replace \r\n, \r, \n occurrences with the PHP_EOL value.
    |
    | WARNING: This feature is DEPRECATED and currently available only
    |          for backwards compatibility purposes!
    |
    */
    $config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global XSS Filtering
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
    | COOKIE data is encountered
    |
    | WARNING: This feature is DEPRECATED and currently available only
    |          for backwards compatibility purposes!
    |
    */
    $config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross Site Request Forgery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
    | checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
    | recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
    |
    | 'csrf_token_name' = The token name
    | 'csrf_cookie_name' = The cookie name
    | 'csrf_expire' = The number in seconds the token should expire.
    | 'csrf_regenerate' = Regenerate token on every submission
    | 'csrf_exclude_uris' = Array of URIs which ignore CSRF checks
    */
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    $config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
    $config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
    $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
    $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
    $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Output Compression
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enables Gzip output compression for faster page loads.  When enabled,
    | the output class will test whether your server supports Gzip.
    | Even if it does, however, not all browsers support compression
    | so enable only if you are reasonably sure your visitors can handle it.
    |
    | Only used if zlib.output_compression is turned off in your php.ini.
    | Please do not use it together with httpd-level output compression.
    |
    | VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it
    | means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
    | even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  For
    | compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
    | by the output class.  Do not 'echo' any values with compression enabled.
    |
    */
    $config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Master Time Reference
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Options are 'local' or any PHP supported timezone. This preference tells
    | the system whether to use your server's local time as the master 'now'
    | reference, or convert it to the configured one timezone. See the 'date
    | helper' page of the user guide for information regarding date handling.
    |
    */
    $config['time_reference'] = 'local';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Rewrite PHP Short Tags
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
    | can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
    | in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
    |
    | Note: You need to have eval() enabled for this to work.
    |
    */
    $config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverse Proxy IPs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy
    | IP addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust headers such as
    | HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_CLIENT_IP in order to properly identify
    | the visitor's IP address.
    |
    | You can use both an array or a comma-separated list of proxy addresses,
    | as well as specifying whole subnets. Here are a few examples:
    |
    | Comma-separated:  '10.0.1.200,192.168.5.0/24'
    | Array:        array('10.0.1.200', '192.168.5.0/24')
    */
    $config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

that's the problem, i don''t know hot to config my code into iis server
btw i'm using codeiginter 3 and ii server

hope anyone can help mee

**Edit**
This is how i managing my route.php

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    /*
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | URI ROUTING
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
    |
    | Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
    | and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
    | URL normally follow this pattern:
    |
    | example.com/class/method/id/
    |
    | In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
    | so that a different class/function is called than the one
    | corresponding to the URL.
    |
    | Please see the user guide for complete details:
    |
    | https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
    |
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RESERVED ROUTES
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | There are three reserved routes:
    |
    | $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
    |
    | This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
    | URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
    | would be loaded.
    |
    | $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
    |
    | This route will tell the Router which controller/method to use if those
    | provided in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
    |
    | $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
    |
    | This is not exactly a route, but allows you to automatically route
    | controller and method names that contain dashes. '-' isn't a valid
    | class or method name character, so it requires translation.
    | When you set this option to TRUE, it will replace ALL dashes in the
    | controller and method URI segments.
    |
    | Examples: my-controller/index -> my_controller/index
    |   my-controller/my-method -> my_controller/my_method
    */
    $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
    $route['404_override'] = '';
    $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;

    /*
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sample REST API Routes
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    $route['api/example/users/(:num)'] = 'api/example/users/id/$1'; // Example 4
    $route['api/example/users/(:num)(\.)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)'] = 'api/example/users/id/$1/format/$3$4'; // Example 8
```

Comment: You have to set base_url config = 'http://localhost:8081/' you have to change in production. show you routes.php file how you are setting routes.

Comment: i've already change the base_url but i still got an bad request

Comment: I suggest you use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.